# Minkowski sum alternative notation

Tags: symbols

The [Minkowski sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_addition) of two polytopes is pretty neat. I'm working with a lot of them right now, and Minkowski sum of simplices, which write as stuff like:

```
\sum y_I \text{ conv } \{e_i | i \in I \}
```

So my problem arises when I want to talk about the vector space freely generated by these objects, so I have formal sums and Minkowski sums which should **absolutely not** have the same notation. When I'm adding two polytopes is all good as I can use '+' and '+^M' and is reasonably clear.
For the sum symbol I tried to use the '^M' trick but looks bad (looks liek M is one of the limits of the sum).

Any ideas? Anyone that had a similar problem? Thanks!

EDIT: MWE as per requested:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\title{Minkowski Sum}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\begin{document}
Let be the Minkowski sum $ Q_I = \sum_{I \subseteq J}  \text{ conv } \{e_j | j \in J \} $ and consider the formal sum of polytopes:
$$ \sum_{I \subseteq J \subseteq \{1, \cdots , n\}} \text{ conv } \{e_j | j \in J \}  = \sum_{J \subseteq \{1, \cdots , n\}} 2^{\# J } \text{ conv } \{e_j | j \in J \} $$

Which is dangerously confusing as it is completely different from
$$\sum_{I \subseteq J \subseteq \{1, \cdots , n\}} \text{ conv } \{e_j | j \in J \} $$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Please add an MWE and tell us what you want. If you are confused, read https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx

Comment: I really don't see much of a point on adding the MWE but here it goes.

Comment: Do you want us to advise you a good notation? If yes, then ask on math.stackexchange. If you want help typesetting something, then tell what you want to typeset.

Comment: And also, use `\mathrm{conv}`, not `\text{conv}`.

Comment: Could you just use some notation around a set to mean the formal vector space freely generated by it, and then the sums are all Minkowski sums, within that vector space or within the origin vector space?

Comment: @MichaelFraiman Thanks, those were useful comments! I'll head over to math.stack and if I find a solution there I close this question.

Comment: @BenjaminMcKay I see your idea, which is kind of the dual idea of representing it as a vector indexed by polytopes. However I use the associativity of both sums quite often so I don't think is ideal.

Comment: If the question is about placement of `M` to decorate the sum symbol, then consider using `\sideset{}{^M}\sum...` (from `amsmath`).  But Benjamin McKay's suggestion is probably better.

Comment: @AndrewSwann is it possible to put the superscript before the sum symbol?

Comment: It is ugly to type, but a pre-superscript can be obtained for the `\sum` with `\mathop{\llap{$^M$}\sum}\limits_{I \subseteq J \subseteq \{1, \cdots , n\}} \text{ conv } \{e_j | j \in J \}`

Comment: I'll use a macro for it, with some \quad spacing behind, and I'm already happy, something like: \newcommand{\msum}{\quad \mathop{\llap{$^M$}\sum}\limits}

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes if you add it as an answer I think I can close this

Comment: Yes, `\sideset{^M}{}\sum...`, see the [`amsmath` documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath?lang=en)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the comments, the OP mused whether a pre-superscript could be added to the `\sum`, as that might be sufficient to clarify the notation.  The answer is, yes it can, but the actual syntax, in this particular case, turns out to be a little tedious.  Normally `^2x_1` is sufficient for getting a superscript `2` before the `x`.  However, in this case,

```
^M\sum_{...}
```

has the problem that if the underset is too wide, the `M` gets pushed leftward.  At first, one might think that adding a group

```
{^M\sum}_{...}
```

might fix it, but that breaks the underscript, converting into a normal subscript.  The normal fix for this is to add `\limits` to the scripts, but that can only be applied to math operators, as in

```
\mathop{^M\sum}\limits_{...}
```

The only problem with this is that it centers the underset not directly under the `\sum`, because of the width of the `M`.  So the final correction is to lap the pre-script as in

```
\mathop{\mathllap{^M}\sum}\limits_{...}
```

The `\mathllap` requires the `mathtools` package.  Thus, we finally arrive at

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\[\mathop{\mathllap{^M}\sum}\limits_{I \subseteq J \subseteq \{1, \cdots , n\}} 
  \text{ conv } \{e_j | j \in J \}\]

  $\mathop{^M\sum}\limits_{...}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

The `amsmath` package provides the `\sideset` command whose syntax is

```
\sideset{^a_b}{^c_d}\sum
```

placing `a` as presuperscript, `b` as a presubscript, and `c`, `d` in corresponding positions after.  Thus you could use `\sideset{^M}{}\sum` for your situation:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareMathOperator{\conv}{conv}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \sideset{^M}{}\sum_{I\subset J\subset\{1,\dots,n\}}
  \conv\{e_j\mid j\in J\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

You can package this up in a new command `\msum` as follows:

```
\newcommand{\msum}{\sideset{^M}{}\sum}
```

Additionally, as Arzigoglu mentions, in the particular case with the long subscript, you might consider using `\mathclap` from the `mathtools` package to improve the spacing

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\DeclareMathOperator{\conv}{conv}
\newcommand{\msum}{\sideset{^M}{}\sum}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
  \msum_{\mathclap{I\subset J\subset\{1,\dots,n\}}} \mkern10mu
  \conv\{e_j\mid j\in J\}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image: Second sample]

Comment: +1. I prefer this solution. Probably something like `\sideset{^M}{}\sum_{\mathclap{I\subset J\subset\{1,\dots,n\}}}\;\;\conv\{e_j\mid j\in J\}` with `mathtools` looks better.

Comment: @Arzigoglu Thank you.  Yes, depending on the circumstances, using `\mathclap` from `mathtools` can indeed improve the spacing.

Comment: Very instructive, as \sideset might be useful for other stuff as well. Thanks!